# Memcpy is not working in C Low level program

Tags: c, serial-port, microcontroller

I got stuck badly in this program function, i have no idea why this memcpy function is not able to copy thecharacters in to the local_buf. I have tried in Visual studio it works fine but when i use in my microcontroller SDK which is c based, it dosent work or if works then copy some garbage values.

I couldnt find anything wrong and lot of people do the same thing, is there any other better way to do it or some suggestion in the low level program instead of memcpy

```
static void Transmit_Async(void)
{    
     char local_buff[10];
      int i;


 for(i=0;i<10;i++)
     {

    if(buffer[i]=='\r')
        {
        memcpy(local_buff,buffer,i);
        memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
         }
       }

        if(local_buff=='N')
        {
          Text_Write("N12345678\r");
           memset(local_buff,0,sizeof(local_buff));
           }

        if(local_buff=='C')
        {
          Text_Write("\r");
            memset(local_buff,0,sizeof(local_buff));
           }

         if(local_buff=='V')
        {
          Text_Write("9865");
          memset(local_buff,0,sizeof(local_buff));
          }

        LED0 = LED_ON; 
        LED1 = LED_OFF; 

}
```

Comment: `local_buff=='...'` seems suspicious.

Comment: Can we see your definition of `buffer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you mean that your `if(local_buff=='...')` statements do not seem to work, then the problem is that those comparisons will never work. `local_buff` is an array of `char`, and you are comparing it with a literal character (which actually has type `int` in C). They are of different types, and you cannot expect a character constant to compare successfully with a pointer value anyway.

What you probably mean is:

```
        if(local_buff[0]=='N')
```

or whatever the appropriate index should be for where you expect the comparison to start.